# Problems with colorbar range matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to set my colorbar so I can see difference between the small values with different colors. For exeample: two different colors between 0.4 and 0.6.
But my maximum value is 3, which makes hard to see this values. 
How can I set different intervals for different colors in the colorbar so I can see this difference?
I tried Boundary norm and Log, but doesn't work
I am attaching some plots to ilustrate.

[image: Colorbar with normal range]

[image: Colorbar with set_ticks]

Comment: I've never tried this, but can you have multiple colorbars with different palettes for different ranges?  You might have to segregate your data into multiple ```ndarrays```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta = 0.025

x = y = np.arange(0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10e1 * (Z1*Z2)    # Random function creation
levels = np.array([0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,2,3])

fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

CF = ax1.contourf(X,Y,Z,
         levels = levels,
         cmap = plt.cm.spectral
        )
CS = ax1.contour(X,Y,Z,
         colors = 'k',    # Black border
         levels = levels
        )


cbar = plt.colorbar(CF, ticks=levels, format='%.2f')
plt.show()
```

[image]